# cannot run grails app from Terminal window

Tags: grails

I need some help for running grails app. I am using Grails 1.3.7 on my Mac with OSx Lion. I used to run grails application fine from the command line/terminal window fine. But recently since I installed Intellij Idea and started running grails app thru Intellij Idea. But now I cannot run the same application from terminal window. In console, my application goes upto ... 'running grails application' and then never go further. I can see the java process in 'Activity Monitor' but the app never go further..  Appreciate help to determine why I cannot run app from terminal now, and runs fine when launched thru IntellijIdea.

From Terminal window

```
YSINGH_XXX:Trunk_AS ysingh$ grails run-app
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /Users/ysingh/Grails/grails-1.3.7

Base Directory: /Users/ysingh/Workspace/Trunk/Trunk_AS
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 2369ms.
Running script /Users/ysingh/Grails/grails-1.3.7/scripts/RunApp.groovy
Environment set to development
  [groovyc] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/ysingh/.grails/1.3.7/projects/Trunk_AS/ast/mongodb-morphia
  [groovyc] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/ysingh/Workspace/Trunk/Trunk_AS/target/classes
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /Users/ysingh/.grails/1.3.7/projects/Trunk_AS
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/ysingh/.grails/1.3.7/projects/Trunk_AS/tomcat
Running Grails application..

==============  This is the last statement in console......
```

Comment: Are you sure it's *not* running?  What happens when you go to  http://localhost:8080 in browser?

Comment: Also, have you tried creating a new (empty) grails app? I'm running grails 1.3.7 on Mac OS X Lion no probs.

Comment: Maybe related to dependecies resolution... try deleting ~/.m2 and ~/.grails

Comment: My above comments were for my work computer, which came fresh with Lion.  However, my home laptop I just upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion and ran in to this problem.  I ended up having to install “Java for Mac OS X 10.7 Developer" (see here: http://www.devinbaldwin.com/2011/10/25/install-grails-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/) and reboot.